# Tomcat fail to start after 1st successful run

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:~# sudo systemctl start tomcat

root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:~# sudo systemctl status tomcat

● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container

Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-11-05 17:40:01 UTC; 3s ago

Process: 19639 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Process: 19624 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Main PID: 19636 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 05 17:40:01 ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Nov 05 17:40:01 ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.

Nov 05 17:40:01 ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Is the process already running? `ps aux|grep java` It will fail to start if it can not bind to a port.

Comment: Doesn't `systemd` have some kind of "run the script in debug mode" feature? (If not, it would be the only feature it *didn't* have).

Comment: when I use # tail -f catalina.out command